# Style CSS of year and month selects jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to style the selects in a jQuery datepicker object. For instance, neither do the following work.

```
.ui-datepicker.year.select {
 width:200px;
}

.ui-datepicker.select {
width:200px;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume the CSS file for the datepicker is called after the CSS file where you tried to override those things?

Comment: @antseburova  No separate CSS files other than ones included with jquery CDN

Comment: Can you post your HTML and JS as well? I'm guessing you should be adding a space between the class names if the `select` elements are *inside* the datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example. The UI Sheet seems to override, so I used `!important`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/whcjw3w6/

**HTML**

```
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
select.ui-datepicker-month,
select.ui-datepicker-year {
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

Per [@mike-mccaughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/mike-mccaughan) comment, you can do this as well:

```
.ui-datepicker-header select.ui-datepicker-month,
.ui-datepicker-header select.ui-datepicker-year {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Just had to specify the selector more.

Comment: Or you could just make the selector more specific, which is preferred over `!important`.